# Can't get all order items & keep getting orders lines which have sub-components

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi I hope someone can help me or give me a clue on a SQL query I need to develop a Pick List report in Crystal Report 2008. The following query on displays order lines of items which have sub-components of a parent part and NOT order lines of items which are not sub-components and just stand alone items. We need all order lines to be displayed. Can someone please assist with this?

```
SELECT "SorMaster"."SalesOrder",
       "SorMaster"."Customer",
       "SorMaster"."OrderDate",
       "CusSorMaster_"."CheckedBy",
       "ArCustomer"."SoldToAddr1",
       "ArCustomer"."SoldToAddr2",
       "ArCustomer"."SoldToAddr3",
       "ArCustomer"."SoldToAddr4",
       "ArCustomer"."SoldToAddr5",
       "ArCustomer"."SoldPostalCode",
       "SorMaster"."ShipAddress1",
       "SorMaster"."ShipAddress2",
       "SorMaster"."ShipAddress3",
       "SorMaster"."ShipAddress4",
       "SorMaster"."ShipAddress5",
       "SorMaster"."ShipPostalCode",
       "ArCustomer"."Name",
       "SorMaster"."CustomerName",
       "SorMaster"."CustomerPoNumber",
       "CusSorMaster_"."CusJobRef",
       "SorDetail"."MOrderQty",
       "SorDetail"."MStockDes",
       "SorDetail"."MBackOrderQty",
       "SorDetail"."MShipQty",
       "SorMaster"."ReqShipDate",
       "SorDetail"."LineType",
       "SorMaster"."ShippingInstrs",
       "SorMaster"."Salesperson",
       "SorDetail"."MStockCode",
       "InvWarehouse"."DefaultBin",
       "BomNarration"."Narration",
       "BomStructure"."Component",
       "InvMaster"."Description",
       "BomStructure"."QtyPer"
FROM("SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."InvMaster" "InvMaster"
     INNER JOIN((((("SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."SorDetail" "SorDetail"
                    INNER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."InvWarehouse" "InvWarehouse" ON ("SorDetail"."MStockCode" = "InvWarehouse"."StockCode")
                                                                                   AND ("SorDetail"."MWarehouse" = "InvWarehouse"."Warehouse"))
                   INNER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."SorMaster" "SorMaster" ON "SorDetail"."SalesOrder" = "SorMaster"."SalesOrder")
                  INNER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."BomStructure" "BomStructure" ON "SorDetail"."MStockCode" = "BomStructure"."ParentPart")
                 INNER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."CusSorMaster+" "CusSorMaster_" ON "SorMaster"."SalesOrder" = "CusSorMaster_"."SalesOrder")
                FULL OUTER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."ArCustomer" "ArCustomer" ON "SorMaster"."Customer" = "ArCustomer"."Customer")ON "InvMaster"."StockCode" = "BomStructure"."Component")
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."BomNarration" "BomNarration" ON "BomStructure"."AutoNarrCode" = "BomNarration"."NarrationNum"
WHERE ("SorDetail"."LineType" = '1'
    OR "SorDetail"."LineType" = '7')
ORDER BY "SorMaster"."SalesOrder",
         "SorDetail"."MStockCode",
         "InvWarehouse"."DefaultBin";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the JOIN on BomStructure as you want the items that are not in this table. You can try stg like this but I am a bit scared about the performances :

```
SELECT "SorMaster"."SalesOrder",
--- ... No change between these lines ...
       "InvWarehouse"."DefaultBin",
       tmpBom."Narration",
       tmpBom."Component",
       tmpBom."Description",
       tmpBom."QtyPer"
FROM    
        (           
            (

                "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."SorDetail" "SorDetail"
                INNER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."InvWarehouse" "InvWarehouse" ON ("SorDetail"."MStockCode" = "InvWarehouse"."StockCode") AND ("SorDetail"."MWarehouse" = "InvWarehouse"."Warehouse")
                INNER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."SorMaster" "SorMaster" ON "SorDetail"."SalesOrder" = "SorMaster"."SalesOrder"
                INNER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."CusSorMaster+" "CusSorMaster_" ON "SorMaster"."SalesOrder" = "CusSorMaster_"."SalesOrder"
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT  InvMaster.Code AS Component, InvMaster.Description, BomStructure.QtyPer, BomNarration.Narration, ISNULL(BomStructure.ParentPart, InvMaster.StockCode) AS ParentOrOrphan
                    FROM    "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."InvMaster" "InvMaster" 
                            LEFT JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."BomStructure" ON "BomStructure"."Component" = "InvMaster"."StockCode"
                            LEFT JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."BomNarration" "BomNarration" ON "BomStructure"."AutoNarrCode" = "BomNarration"."NarrationNum"
                    ) tmpBom ON "SorDetail"."MStockCode" = tmpBom.ParentOrOrphan
            )
        )
        FULL OUTER JOIN "SysproCompanyT"."dbo"."ArCustomer" "ArCustomer" ON "SorMaster"."Customer" = "ArCustomer"."Customer"
WHERE ("SorDetail"."LineType" = '1' OR "SorDetail"."LineType" = '7')
-- TO BE REPLACED BY : WHERE ("SorDetail"."LineType" IN ('1', '7')
ORDER BY "SorMaster"."SalesOrder",
         "SorDetail"."MStockCode",
         "InvWarehouse"."DefaultBin";
```

Comment: The ```tmpBom``` subquery should return the pairs {component ; parent } for subcomponent and {material;material} for the items not in the BOM

Comment: Another option is the use of  ```UNION ALL``` instead of subquery :

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I need to find out if there is a way to translate this in Crystal reports 2008.

Comment: Try to create a view with this query in SQL Server and just call ```SELECT ... FROM myView``` in Crystal Reports 2008. It should hide the complexity to CR 2008

Answer (score 0):

Does it have anything to do with this bit of the code? Have you selected the LineType that includes the stand alone items?

```
WHERE ("SorDetail"."LineType" = '1'
OR "SorDetail"."LineType" = '7')
```

Comment: No because other orders exist that have these conditions that are not displaying.

Comment: Can I have a bit more context here? Does LineType indicate whether the order line is a sub component or a stand alone? If yes, what are the LineType values for the stand alone order lines and sub components?

Comment: Line type is one of the following 1. stocked, 2. non-stocked, 3. Freight, 4. Misc, 5. Comment, 6. standard comment, 7. Service charge. We only want to see orders with stocked items and have service charge hence included in the query. it has no bearing on whether the item is a sub-component or not.